# Route around whole polygon

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, area

Are there some ready tools (preferably in Google Maps API) or algorithms for creating the shortest route to fly around whole given polygon? E.g. You have the drone and you should take photo of some given area. So, how to build the most optimal route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, obviously, there is no such ready tool in Google Maps API. For the resolving this particular problem you should have the square of photo, that is taken by drone. It is easy to count it with height of iron flight and some other camera properties.

Then we should just create the shortest route between the centers of photos and it is a classical sample of traveling salesman problem. Here is the resolving of it: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp.

Hope, this will help somebody!